# How to describe React createElement parameter type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

`React.createElement` parameter type is `[string, { [prop: any]: string }, [string | [string, {[prop: any]: string}, ...repeatedHere]`

The question is how do I extract this parameters type ?

My attempt so far:

`type VNode = [string, { [props: string]: string }, (string | VNode)[]];` but it's clearly not working.

So I can do:

`createElement(rootNode: VNode)`

Answer (score 0):

> React.createElement parameter type is [string, { [prop: any]: string }, [string | [string, {[prop: any]: string}, ...repeatedHere]

This is incorrect. Cannot find it in the definitions : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts

## Still answering the question

> My attempt so far:

Your attempt is valid. *If* you have `createElement(foo:SomeTypeSignature)` then you can do `type SomeType = SomeTypeSignature` 100%